# Getting undefined value when trying to access json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am fetching some json data from the api http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=batman&y=&plot=full&r=js.

Printing out text in console giving me correct data. However when I am trying to access any of its properties its giving me undefined.

```
    var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=batman&y=&plot=full&r=json";
    request.get(url, function(err, res){        
    if (this.isMounted()) {
     this.setState({data : res.text});
    }

    }.bind(this));
```

If I try below one it's printing correct data

```
  console.log(this.state.data);
```

But if I try below it's giving me    undefined.

```
  console.log(this.state.data.Title);
```

Comment: Try with: this.state.data.data.Title

Comment: @AndreaM16 What would that do?

Comment: I guess that it is an object and you get undefined cause of that. If you use this.state.data.data you'll be able to access what you are looking for, or, at least, this is how I usually solve this kind of things.

Comment: still undefined :(

Comment: Try setting up a Plunker or a JSFiddle reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove res.text property.Also try to log res in the console and see if its an object

```
var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=batman&y=&plot=full&r=json";
    request.get(url, function(err, res){        
    if (this.isMounted()) {
     this.setState({data : res});
    }

    }.bind(this));
```